# Find and return the node with the next larger element in a generic tree

Tags: java, generics, tree

I am using a different approach. But only two test cases are successfully running. Here's my code:

```
public static TreeNode<Integer> findNextLargerNode(TreeNode<Integer> root, int n){
    Queue<TreeNode<Integer>>pendingNodes = new LinkedList<>();
    pendingNodes.add(root);
    if(root == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    if(root.data > n)
    {
        return root;
    }
    while(pendingNodes.size()!=0)
    {
        TreeNode<Integer> front = pendingNodes.remove();
        for(int i =0; i<front.children.size(); i++)
        {
            pendingNodes.add(front.children.get(i));
            if(front.children.get(i).data > n)
            {
                return front.children.get(i);
            }
         }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Where have I made errors?

Comment: What do you mean by 'the next larger element'? Do you seek for the max data in the tree? Highest data in the tree that bigger then n? Can you please elaborate so we can help you?

Comment: Next larger element means value which is just greater than n.
For example, if a tree contains nodes with data values : 10,20,30,40,50 and, if n=18(say), then output should be 20.

Comment: Did this answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

You have two main errors in your code:

1. `if(root.data > n) return root;`
   Consider the following tree:

   ```
     40
    /  \ 
   10   30
   ```

   Now what happens if you run your function with n=15? The root is bigger than n, and therefore returns 40, but not 30 as the required output.
2. `if(front.children.get(i).data > n) return front.children.get(i);`

   Consider the following example:

   ```
     40
    /  \ 
   20   18
   ```

   Again, run with n=15, and you will get 20 as the first child checked on the root. The function returns and does not continue to check other more suitable nodes.

Your **simplest** way (surely not the shortest) to achieve that can use the following algorithm:

1. Traverse on all node (BFS or DFS) and export data to an array
2. Find the next bigger element of n
3. Traverse on the tree and find the node with that data

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
if(front.children.get(i).data > n)
```

By this `if` statement the next any greater element will be returned.

It goes right with a case like:

```
21
10 3 20 30 40 2 40 50 0 0 0 0
```

but a case like:

```
21
10 3 20 20 40 2 40 30 0 0 0 0
```

It will return 40 while we need 30 as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static TreeNode<Integer> findNextLargerNode2(TreeNode<Integer> root, int n){
        if(root==null) {return null;}
        TreeNode<Integer> ans=null;
        if(root.data>n) {
            ans=root;
        }
        for(TreeNode<Integer> child: root.children) {
            TreeNode<Integer> childans=findNextLargerNode2(child,n);
            if(childans!=null) {
                if(ans==null || ans.data>childans.data) {
                    ans=childans;
                }
            }
        }
        return ans;
    
    }
```

Comment: This is the best approach and it works 100 %